# Can I highlight chunks of code in Dreamweaver?

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver, highlighting

I posted this earlier but got no replies, I don't think it was tagged very well :(

Anyway, I've googled this question and can't find anything. What I would like to know is if it was possible to highlight code in Dreamweaver so it's easier to navigate around my code as it gets a little confusing the more code I add.

This is what I've mocked up to give you an idea of what I would hope is possible:

[image]

Hope someone can clarify if this is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can do is click on a numbered row of code and shift + click on a numbered row say 50 lines down or whatever. You will see a "-" symbol. If you click that, it will condense your code. I know that's not exactly what you were looking for, but it will help keep things organized and readable.

Comment: Oh, that's quite good if there is no other way. Thanks @Phorden

Comment: @DrRobotnik I am not sure if there is no other way, but this is common practice in any IDE that you have a lot of code in to keep things organized. I would suggest doing it this way.

Comment: Sadly, I believe the latest update of Dreamweaver has taken away this function :(